# Writing the meta:generator tag in Excel XLS file from PHP script or linux command line

Tags: php, excel, bash, xls

I need to manipulate XLS files from PHP.
I found the great library [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) which does 99% all of the job I need. Sadly I miss that 1%, which is writing the name of the "Creating application" (gnumeric sees it as *meta:generator*) in Excel 2007 files (*Excel5* as called in the library).

Is there any other way to write this tag?

I can work around this by converting the XLS to gnumeric (using `ssconvert`), adding the tag to the XML file and convert back to XLS, but since I should use this script in a headless server I'd rather avoid installing gnumeric.

Any help is appreciated, even if another method exists (a command line tool, another PHP library).

Comment: Are these XLS files guaranteed to be xlsx, IOW xml?

Comment: No, old style office 2007/XP XLS files, no XML. I mentioned XML because gnumeric's file format is xml based

Comment: Is this "Creating Application" an extended property? Do you have an xlsx/xls file that contains it that you could provide to an issue on the PHPExcel github repo?

Comment: @MarkBaker in Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php, row 1326. I thought I found an issue about that but cannot find it anymore, and in that issue I read you were not accepting anymore issues for Excel5 reader/writer. Anyway I have a demo file if you need it

Comment: We've never not accepted issues for any component (though I do close duplicate issues). Currently a lot of the PHPExcel code is being rewritten from scratch for version 2, but the 1.x branch is still alive and kicking and has been extended beyond its anticipated lifespan despite my desire to force a minimum of PHP 5.3 so it can take advantage of a lot of the new features that have been added to PHP over the last few years

Comment: But post it as an issue, and if you could provide an example file that would certainly help

Comment: My mistake, I will open a new issue ASAP

Comment: Issue opened! https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/332

Comment: @MarkBaker, is there any branch I can use now for basic reading/writing which has support for writing that property?

Comment: At the moment, no! It'll appear in the develop branch when it appears

Comment: ok thanks! I'll keep watching